# Error compiling MAUI project - missing MonoAOTCompiler.Task

Tags: maui, visual-studio-mac-2022

I'm creating a MAUI application targeting iOS and Android. I have been using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac version 17.3. That version doesn't really support archiving the app, so I installed version 17.4 preview 2.1. When I try to compile my app I get the following error:

Unable to find Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task

I found a post that indicated I should run the command:
dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task --version 7.0.0-rc.2.22472.3

When I run that command in terminal I get the error:
error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'version')

Everything I have found indicated that the problem should have been fixed in Preview 2.1 of Visual Studio 2022 for Mac, but it is still occurring.

Can anyone help me resolve this? I need to publish my app to the stores and can't get it to compile in release mode or create the archive because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the package to your project.

First, you should right click your project name and choose the `Manage Nuget packages` button.

[image]

Second, you can search the package `Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task` and install it.
[image]

Then you successfully add the package to your project.

Comment: Attempting to add that package fails. The following error occurs 3 times, followed by the message that Package Restore failed Rolling back package changes for <Project Name>. Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0...
The local source '/Users/davidrutter/.nuget/NuGet/Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task' doesn't exist.

Comment: The error with the MonoAOTCompiler.Task only shows up in Release configuration.

Comment: You can do the following steps:
1. Open VS Tools
2. Choose Options
3. Nuget Package Manager
4. General
5. Clear All Nuget Cache(s).

Comment: Clearing the Nuget Cache fixed the problem. Thank you.